# How to record high quality footage for a game trailer?

Tags: unreal, unreal-5, marketing, video, trailer

I'm trying to record a trailer for my game using OBS, but the recordings are coming out in very poor quality. I've tried increasing the video bitrate, but that just makes the game lag during recording. How can I improve the recording quality without causing lag?

System Specs:

CPU: i7 9th gen
GPU: GTX 1650
RAM: 16 GB

Comment: It should be possible with OBS with the right set-up, you probably need to adjust settings further. I had a similar experience with OBS and at the time it was resolved by changing the color format at Settings->Advanced->Video.

Comment: I have a worse card than you and I manage 1080p 60fps on OBS with no strain at all, perhaps adjust the settings or look online for an OBS quality settings tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the workload of both running the game and encoding the video is straining your system, you may want to invest in a separate capture device.

This is an external device that either acts as a monitor or as a pass-through between your PC and your existing monitor, and handles recording the video (and audio signals) passing through that connection.

Because it handles this workload external to your PC, your computer's resources can remain 100% devoted to keeping the game's framerate up at a high resolution, and load spikes won't cause video quality to suffer or add stutters.

A quick search for "game capture device" will turn up a number of options you can evaluate.

Comment: they vary greatly in price. I intend to record 30 fps at 1080p. What kind of a card would be sufficient for that?

Comment: We don't answer technology recommendation questions on this particular site, including suggesting specific hardware models.